# Ajax add to cart not working in wordpress 5.6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

This code is supposed to add products with ajax to woocommerce cart in product page, everything is ok buy when wordpress 5.6 is released but when the Jquery library is updated this code doesn't work in variation products. please help to solve this Jquery conflict. This problem not in simple products and simple products added to cart very well.

```
<?php

/**
 * JS for AJAX Add to Cart handling
 */
function ace_product_page_ajax_add_to_cart_js() {
    global $post;
    if('product' == $post->post_type) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        jQuery(function($) {

            $('form.cart').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var form = $(this);
                form.block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#fff', opacity: 0.6 } });

                var formData = new FormData(form.context);
                formData.append('add-to-cart', form.find('[name=add-to-cart]').val() );

                // Ajax action.
                $.ajax({
                    url: wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'ace_add_to_cart' ),
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'POST',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    complete: function( response ) {
                        response = response.responseJSON;

                        if ( ! response ) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if ( response.error && response.product_url ) {
                            window.location = response.product_url;
                            return;
                        }

                        // Redirect to cart option
                        if ( wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_redirect_after_add === 'yes' ) {
                            window.location = wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url;
                            return;
                        }

                        var $thisbutton = form.find('.single_add_to_cart_button'); //
//                      var $thisbutton = null; // uncomment this if you don't want the 'View cart' button

                        // Trigger event so themes can refresh other areas.
                        $( document.body ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton ] );

                        // Remove existing notices
                        $( 'form.cart .added_to_cart' ).remove();
                        $( '.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-info' ).remove();
                        // Add new notices
                        form.closest('.product').before(response.fragments.notices_html)

                        form.unblock();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script><?php 
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ace_product_page_ajax_add_to_cart_js' );

/**
 * Add to cart handler.
 */
function ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler() {
    WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action();
    WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();
}
add_action( 'wc_ajax_ace_add_to_cart', 'ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler' );
add_action( 'wc_ajax_nopriv_ace_add_to_cart', 'ace_ajax_add_to_cart_handler' );

// Remove WC Core add to cart handler to prevent double-add
remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

/**
 * Add fragments for notices.
 */
function ace_ajax_add_to_cart_add_fragments( $fragments ) {
    $all_notices  = WC()->session->get( 'wc_notices', array() );
    $notice_types = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_notice_types', array( 'error', 'success', 'notice' ) );

    ob_start();
    foreach ( $notice_types as $notice_type ) {
        if ( wc_notice_count( $notice_type ) > 0 ) {
            wc_get_template( "notices/{$notice_type}.php", array(
                'notices' => array_filter( $all_notices[ $notice_type ] ),
            ) );
        }
    }
    $fragments['notices_html'] = ob_get_clean();

    wc_clear_notices();

    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'ace_ajax_add_to_cart_add_fragments' );
```

Comment: You need to post the console errors also, then anyone able to make suggestions.

Comment: @Onkar Singh Unfortunately there is no console error!

Comment: hmm, so you need to create some test page where somebody checks and tests it, by looking it seems good and there is no error.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by changing following line:

```
 var formData = new FormData(form.context);
```

to:

```
 var formData = new FormData(this);
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me hours of figuring this out!!